# Automatically compress image after uploading to Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-photos

I wrote a php script to upload images to my google drive account. However, the storage space is limited and it'll soon be full if I keep uploading images.

I know that in Google Photo, you have a setting called "High Quality", which will automatically compress your images after they're uploaded, so they won't count storage space for those "High Quality" images. Is there a way to achieve it with Google Drive? Since images uploaded to google drive are showed up on google photo as well?

Comment: topic should be: _Automatically compress image BEFORE uploading to Google Drive_

Comment: If I compress image before uploading, will google drive count storage for it? I put it as "after" because Google Photos has that thing: You upload, it compress (not you), then it doesn't count storage for your image.

Comment: `count storage for it?` dont know, but you will upload less data. Mybe load first up to google photo then from goolge photo to google drive. ?!? Then google has compressed it for you:-)

Comment: There is no API method to compress your files in [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/). However you can try to connect 3rd party apps to your Drive as some have done in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524044/is-it-possible-to-convert-videos-in-drive-to-other-lower-size-video-formats-onli). But as for the API, this is not feasible.